# How to pass a http header using a variable in curl using PHP

Tags: php, curl

My code to add header is:

```
$apikey="xyz";
     curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                            'Content-Type: application/json',
                                            'Accept: application/json',
                                            'X-Auth-Token: $apikey'                                 
                                            ));
```

But I am getting an error showing that **This request requires HTTP Authentication.**Now I want to know whether I am right? If Yes why I am getting error.If I am wrong how can do this..

Thankyou,

Comment: try adding this: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);

Comment: This is not working...I am getting same error again...Is there any other option???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use double quotes if you want your variable to be interpolated by PHP, i.e. `"X-Auth-Token: $apikey"`.

For more info see [PHP: Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: Or you can do 'X-Auth-Token: '.$apikey

Answer (score 0):

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http:www.example.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('name' => 'Bhuvanagiri Gireesh') );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'key: license-key ';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

**There are many ways to achieve it but, this is the easiest way to add headers in curl**